# Falstad - a bug with mosfets?

Tags: mosfet, current, fault, connect, falstad

I have a schematic in Falstad. It is **almost** symmetrical (the mosfets are connected by drains and "SWAP D/S" is enable in the second mosfet to be able to connect both).

And this symmetrical circuit behaves asymmetrically.

[image]

Here is a text file with this circuit:

```
$ 1 0.000005 10.20027730826997 50 5 50 5e-11
f 256 288 256 384 32 1.5 0.02
f 336 288 336 384 40 1.5 0.02
w 320 384 272 384 0
v 256 0 336 0 0 0 40 5 0 0 0.5
s 256 0 192 0 0 1 false
172 256 224 192 224 0 7 5 5 0 0 0.5 Voltage
s 256 288 256 224 0 1 false
s 336 288 336 224 0 1 false
s 400 96 336 96 0 1 false
w 192 0 160 0 0
w 400 96 432 96 0
w 160 384 240 384 0
w 352 384 432 384 0
w 432 0 336 0 0
w 256 96 160 96 0
w 80 96 80 384 0
w 512 384 512 96 0
172 336 224 400 224 0 7 5 5 0 0 0.5 Voltage
v 336 96 256 96 0 0 40 5 0 0 0.5
w 160 0 160 48 0
w 160 48 160 96 0
w 160 48 80 48 0
w 80 48 80 96 0
w 432 0 432 48 0
w 432 48 432 96 0
w 432 48 512 48 0
w 512 48 512 96 0
w 512 384 432 384 0
w 160 384 80 384 0
x 194 -17 246 -14 4 24 SW1
x 345 146 397 149 4 24 SW2
x 189 291 241 294 4 24 SW3
x 351 293 403 296 4 24 SW4
x 261 350 270 353 4 12 G
x 341 350 350 353 4 12 G
x 230 399 238 402 4 12 S
x 274 399 282 402 4 12 D
x 309 399 317 402 4 12 D
x 355 399 363 402 4 12 S
```

If SW3, SW4, **SW2** switches are opened and **SW1** is closed, the current does not flow through mosfets.

But if SW3, SW4, **SW1** switches are opened and **SW2** is closed, the current flows.

Is this a bug?

Regards:)

Comment: 1) I see +5 V nets but no ground net, so basically the rest of the circuit is **floating** meaning anything can happen. This is also unrealistic. 2) You cannot switch on/off MOSFETs by applying +5 V or not connecting to anything. You need to apply a proper Vgs (of 5 V or 0 V). You're not doing that. This circuit will not work properly. TLDR: you made a "fantasy circuit" so you get "fanatasy behavior". If you're trying to learn about circuits, then this is the way to more confusion.

Comment: Both of you have right, switching between source and ground for Gate is needed in real life and this rule works in many switching circuits. Buy Bimpelreikkie, trust me - I have checked the original version with that too and I know that it really doesn't matter, because it is not the reason of this fault. It is sad that you don't try to make similar circuit in this software or even better circuit, to simulate this fault.

Comment: why did you inlude S3 and S4 in your circuit? ... they are unused

Comment: Why ask this here instead of on the github issue tracker?

Comment: @Proboszcz You're being awfully confrontational for someone asking about a particular error in a schematic with other known errors. Simulations are garbage in garbage out. If you already know the schematic isn't correct, fix those issues first before asking about it, or at least gracefully acknowledge it instead of insulting someone who points out something in your circuit is wrong other than what you asked about.

Answer (score 3):

Gates are left charged and still control the Ids without Rgs to guarantee turnoff.

- it is not a sim bug, rather a user design fault.

Comment: Not to mention driving the gate relative to something other than the source pin and providing no known reference potential for the 5V gate drive.  Who knows what it is relative to? Not I.

Comment: Right the floating batteries have no ground or 0V anywhere on the design.

Answer (score 1):

**TL;DR;** The java simulator is not a complete circuit analysis tool. It simulates a lot of things in an approximate or ideal nature (i.e. ignoring parasitics, etc.). You should not rely on it for anything more than checking the approximate behaviour of simple circuits.

---

In the case of your example, when you leave SW4 open, the gate is not connected to anything, and so sits at 0V regardless of whatever is around it. When you close SW2, you  drive the source to a negative voltage, which means you now have a positive Vgs which turns the MOSFET on.

The solution (other than using a proper SPICE simulation tool) would be to either connect the gate and source using a high value resistor, or drive it low using an SPDT switch. This will mean that the gate doesn't stay floating at 0V when the source changes (which in practice it wouldn't as there are capacitors between gate and source/drain in a real device).

You should also add diodes going from source to drain of each MOSFET to represent the intrinsic body diode in a practical device.

Comment: The mosfets have built-in internal diodes in this software.

Comment: The simulation does nit bleed gate charge without a resistor. It’s not a simulation error. -1 Although you can set beta and help computes that given RdsOn, Vgs and Vt, you must add Ciss, Coss for the device you choose.